# hibernate filters does not work with subselect query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have Hibernate filters declared in .xml like these:

```xml
<filter name="login" condition="loginUsuario like '%' :loginParam '%'"/>
<filter name="pais" condition="nombreUniversidad in (select u.nombre from Universidad u where u.pais like :paisParam '%')"/>
```

Then in a DAO I call them:

```
if(filters.containsKey("usuario.login")){
    getSession().enableFilter("login").setParameter("loginParam", filters.get("usuario.login"));
}
if(filters.containsKey("universidad.pais.nombre")){
    getSession().enableFilter("pais").setParameter("paisParam", filters.get("universidad.pais.nombre"));
}
```

And then it comes the hql query:

```
List<Contrato> l=getSession.createQuery("select c from Contrato c").list();
```

The first one works fine but the second one fails. I've detected that filters with a subquery fail.

The weird thing is that at home both work fine but when i deploy the application where it must work, the second filter fails. I can not access to the logs or populate all the code with "System.out.println" because it is not development enviroment. I only send them a .WAR archive and they deploy it. I only know that   second filter is not working because i see the screen output of filtered data.

I use the same technology at home (Tomcat 7.0.39 and Mysql 5.1.73) running in windows.
Is a problem of the application server or Mysql server? Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this a database version problem? Are you running locally against a recent copy of your production database?

Comment: I only can call the application from home but i i've replaced filters with a lot of hql queries.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue using the fetch mode of subselect.

It seems there was a bug in hibernate-core and fixed in the latest version.

Here is [the link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7119)